# Tools for maintaining yum repositories

Tags: yum, rpm

Are there any tools for maintaining private yum repositories?

Specifically, I'd like to:

- upload rpms and have them placed in the proper directory;
- indexes/metadata kept-up-to-date automatically;
- keep old versions around;
- reject invalid rpms ( overwriting existing ones for instance ).

---

**Update:**

This will be a repo with my custom-built RPMs, not a mirror of an existing one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Install `yum-utils` (edit: and `createrepo`).

Since a yum repository is just a directory that you run `createrepo(8)` against and serve over http, functions you mention like uploading, keeping old versions around etc can be done with your usual tools like the shell, ssh, rsync etc. Or are you after a kind of attractive web-based method of managing a repo? I'm not sure if one exists.

As for updating metadata automatically, perhaps just use cron? Really, if these are your own packages then you should have tested the rpm before placing it in the repo, so having something check automatically if a rpm is invalid might not be needed, but again a regular cron job with `rpm --test` could tell you.

I'm probably missing some great tools but this has worked for me for our limited needs for years.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you be a bit more explicit please? The binaries from this package don't seem to help.

Comment: createrepo is not available for Centos 4, that was the cause of my confusion. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

As Andrew says, createrepo is all you need.

Put your rpms in a dir, run createrepo on it whenever you add rpms. Expose this dir over http. Add this http url to compatible clients through their /etc/yum.repos.d/ directory .

Comment: What I should have said :)

Answer (score 3):

I use [mrepo](http://dag.wieers.com/home-made/mrepo/) to manage local yum repositories. It is a tool for mirroring repositories and in your case you could set it up to mirror a local directory containing your custom rpms.

Answer (score 2):

http://pulpproject.org/

Answer (score 1):

The HowtoForge has an article regarding a local YUM repo, not sure if its what you are after

can be found > [Here](http://www.howtoforge.com/creating_a_local_yum_repository_centos) <

There are many tutorials regarding local or private repo's

Are you after making your own?

Hope that helps

Comment: Sorry I misread your questions, you are looking for tools to actually maintain your repo?

Comment: I'm looking for tools to maintain a private repo with my custom-built RPMS.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're running Centos5 or later you'll want to install yum-utils, yum-protectbase, and yum-priorities on any machine using your internal repo. When you're running your own repo you can easily shoot yourself in the foot by over writing base RPMs. These packages help avoid that.